# blpapi in Google Colab throwing InvalidArgumentException

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, bloomberg

Trying to run a very vanilla BDP in Google Colab environment. Anyone able to pull this off?

Installed the dependencies:

!pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple/ blpapi

start my session:

```
import blpapi
session = blpapi.Session()
session.start()


session.openService("//blp/refdata")

service = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
request = service.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")

request.append("securities", "USDCAD Curncy")
request.append("fields", "PX_OPEN")

session.sendRequest(request)

endReached = False

while endReached == False:
    ev = session.nextEvent()
    if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE or ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.PARTIAL_RESPONSE:
        for msg in ev:
                
            print (msg)
    if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
        endReached = True
```

This throws me a:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5882776bd4df> in <module>()
      7 
      8 service = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
----> 9 request = service.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
     10 
     11 request.append("securities", "USDCAD Curncy")

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/blpapi/service.py in createRequest(self, operation)
    381             self.__handle,
    382             operation)
--> 383         _ExceptionUtil.raiseOnError(errCode)
    384         return Request(request, self.__sessions)
    385 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/blpapi/exception.py in raiseOnError(errorCode, description)
    144         """
    145         if errorCode:
--> 146             _ExceptionUtil.raiseException(errorCode, description)
    147 
    148 __copyright__ = """

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/blpapi/exception.py in raiseException(errorCode, description)
    136                 description = "Unknown"
    137         errorClass = _ExceptionUtil.__getErrorClass(errorCode)
--> 138         raise errorClass(description, errorCode)
    139 
    140     @staticmethod

InvalidArgumentException: Null service handle (0x00020002)
```

Any pointers appreciate. Thanks

Comment: `InvalidArgumentException: Null service handle (0x00020002)` suggests your session hasn't been established correctly, and getService() hasn't found the service. Check the return code of `session.start()` which is True/False. Also perhaps you can check the state of `service.__handle`. FWIW your code seems to work fine as a Python project (MS Visual Studio on Windows). I am not familiar with Google Colabs: on a PC you need to be logged into a Bloomberg Terminal for the API to work.

Comment: From what I read about Google CoLab it runs in the cloud ... so it is unclear how your code will access the credentials and session information for your Bloomberg account. On a local implementation, the blpapi uses the underlying Bloomberg transport on your PC (bbcomm.exe) which has already been started by logging into the Bloomberg Terminal. The Session.start() call can take a sessionOptions structure which defines the server (default 'localhost', ie IP address 127.0.0.1) and port (default 8194).

Comment: You need to use local runtime for this: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html